# Jquery unable to find form inputs to given form id

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm attempting to run a function on sumbit of a reply form on my website.
These forms are created by Javascript after the page load, so the Jquery is using a **live** function to react to the click of the ".replyformsubmit" class of button.

I need the script to record the input values of the form, but it seems unable to do so.

Currently the ID of the form which houses the button is found, but using it to try and find the input values seems fruitless, it's probably a school boy error but I can't seem to suss it.

Any help would be great.

The Jquery:

```
$(".replyformsubmit").live("click", function(){

var curform = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');//what form is the current one?


var comment = $('#' + curform + ' >  input[name=comment]"').val(); //comes out as undefined
var replyingSerial = $('#' + curform + ' >  input[name=replyingSerial]"').val(); //comes out as undefined

...
```

The script seems unable to find what *comment* and the *replyingSerial* are.

The HTML for a standard example form is:

```
<form action="com.php" method="post" id="replyform_quickreply_1345291318.6107" class="replyform">
<textarea name="comment" type="text" id="commenttextquickreply_1345291318.6107">
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="send!" class="replyformsubmit">
<input type="hidden" style="visibilty: hidden;" name="replyingSerial" value="1345291318.6107"></form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things.  Comment is a textarea, not an input, so if you want to find it you need to use textarea[name=comment].

Second, you can use parent() and find to make your code a little cleaner:

```
$(".replyformsubmit").on("click", function(){
   var parent = $(this).parent();
   var comment= parent.find("textarea[name=comment]");
    alert(comment.val());
});​
```

Comment: Or also `":input[name=comment]"` :)

Comment: Ah, thank you! You've done it. Thanks so much, the little thing was driving me up the wall. Its all coming together now. - I'll accept in the 2 minutes it gives me.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the button is a `submit`, it prevents the rest of the code to be executed.
Use `type='button'` instead.

Or use:

```
$('#formname').submit(function() {
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change input type="submit" to input type="button" as it wont allow other code to get executed afer the submit, and instead of .live() use .on()

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers when content is dynamically added to a page. See the discussion of direct versus delegated events in the .on() method for more information.